# Woocommerce post order item details to API

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to write a little plugin to take the WooCommerce order line item details (title, image url and item url) and post them as a Mailchimp event (giving each line item unique key details). I'm really getting stuck since I'm no developer. It's not sending (I've separately pinged the api with my credentials and it works just fine), but can't work out what's wrong (probably a lot of things).

```
<?php
function send_mailchimp_review_event( $order_id ) {
  
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $mc_email = $order->get_billing_email();

    $url = 'https://us1.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/<123456>/members/' . $mc_email . '/events';

    //initialize product array
    $product_array = [];

    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {

      //get product ID from line items
      $product = wc_get_product($item);

      // get product name, url and thumbnail url
      $mc_product_name = $product->get_name();
      $mc_product_url = get_permalink( $product->get_id() );
      $mc_product_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $product->get_id() ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
      $mc_thumbnail = $mc_product_image[0];
      
    //store in the array with unique keys for each product
     $product_array[] = array(
        'product_name'.$i => $mc_product_name,
        'product_link'.$i => $mc_product_url,
        'product_image'.$i => $mc_thumbnail
      );
        
     $i = $i + 1;   
    }

    $data = wp_remote_post( $url, array(
        'headers'     => array(
            'Authorization' => "Token <mytoken>",
            'Content-Type'  => 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        ),
        'body' => json_encode( array(
           'name' => 'review_request',
            //output the product array within the properties attribute
            'properties' => $product_array
        ) ),
        'method'      => 'POST',
        'data_format' => 'body',
    ) );
}
```

I'm expecting it to send an event to Mailchimp via the API and record an event with the event contents being the line item title, url and product url for each item in the purchase, recorded against a user's profile.